# Getting the Window Title?

Tags: windows, windows-vista

Ok i specify:

My problem is that I want to assign a keyboardshortcut for Dreamweaver CS4 and I have it like this: "C:\Program Files\Adobe\Adobe Dreamweaver CS4\Dreamweaver.exe" Thats ok so far.

But when I press the key it doesn't place itself infront of everything else like Outlook and Visual Studio does, instead it blinks in the taskbar, and I have to click there anyway to get back to Dreamweaver.

Is there any switch or something I can assign for Dreamweaver to get back AND have it "popup?"
OR **some coding with the window title property that fixes this?**

Comment: This question needs clarification. What are you trying to do? In what language? Why does the order of the applications matter?

Answer (score 3):

The Win32 API has a function for enumerating all top level windows on the desktop - EnumWindows ( http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms633497(VS.85).aspx ). Using the enumerated window handle with the Win32 API GetWindowText call ( http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms633520(VS.85).aspx ) would get you that information.

I am unfamiliar with the C# based methods, but I expect there is a similar way there too.

But you did not specify enough information really, what language/tool are you trying to do this within?

Answer (score 1):

Windows tries very hard to prevent applications from shoving themselves in the foreground.  For some reason Windows thinks that CS4 is trying to move itself to the foreground and instead of stealing the focus from the current app in the foreground, it's flashing the icon for the app to let you know that it needs attention.